# How to create a point cloud in a 3D coordinate system with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, points

I want to create a simple point cloud in a coordinate system similar to this one:

[image: img]

but without the axes being annotated by their values.

For these example points:

```
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z 
2.2 14 4 
2.7 23 1
3 13 36
3.55 22 2 
4 15 179
4.5 20 92
4.75 28 78
5.5 23 1
}\datatable
```

Comment: Add Minimum Working Example...

Comment: @sandu I totally forgot. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\addplot3 [only marks] ...` to make a 3D scatter plot and `x`/`y`/`zticklabels={}` to remove the ticklabels?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
X Y Z 
2.2 14 4 
2.7 23 1
3 13 36
3.55 22 2 
4 15 179
4.5 20 92
4.75 28 78
5.5 23 1
}\datatable
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xticklabels={},
  yticklabels={},
  zticklabels={}
]

\addplot3 [only marks] table {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I know it is late, but here is the link to the code that I used:

[Link to The GitHub Repository](https://github.com/salehjg/pointcloud_to_tikz_converter)

Follow the steps in `readme.md` in the repository. Note that [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117140/easiest-way-to-draw-a-3d-coordinate-system-with-axis-labels-and-ticks-in-tikz) has been used as the template.
[image]

Comment: Please consider to upload your tool to https://ctan.org